# Why would a non-UI thread block the UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin

I create and start a thread inside of a button clicked event handler. That thread does some synchronous work and notifies the UI thread of progress by firing an event.

The problem is this locks the UI thread and I'm not sure why.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private event EventHandler<double> ProgressChanged;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
        ProgressChanged += MainPage_ProgressChanged;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (double i = 0; i <= 1; i += .00001)
            {
                ProgressChanged.Invoke(this, i);
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    private void MainPage_ProgressChanged(object sender, double e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            progressBar.Progress = e;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about C#, but isn't the garbage collector going to make issue with the fact the Thread object isn't bound to any global variable? Perhaps it's waiting for the Thread to end so that it can collect Button_Clicked's scope. Just a little theory.

Comment: I'm not sure how garbage collection works in this situation. But I tried making the thread a class-level variable and it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Simple answer is, dont do this, this is a nonsensical application anyway... for instance what app do you know updates the UI that fast? think about all the apps you have seen, what do they do if they need to up the the UI that fast... they throttle their updates. meaning that only update every now and again

Comment: @Havenard - The run-time keeps a reference to running threads. There's no issue here with the GC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Assuming*** a 16.6 ms screen refresh rate on the device, you are firing 100,000 messages into the UI/main thread as *fast* as the `for` loop can execute on a background thread.

Now the UI has to process those messages, (16.6ms * 100,000) / 1000 ms/sec and you have 27 mins of updates. That is just not a practical thing to do.

Comment: `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is setting an action (message) to take place on UI thread, no magic here at all.

Comment: Thumbs up on the answer, but does the main UI thread really wait on a screen refresh for each invoke?.  Don't get me wrong I agree 100,000 invokes blasted at the UI thread is killing things, but is each invoke tied to a screen refresh ?

Comment: @Dweeberly that is a worst-case scenario, **depending** upon which OS we are talking about, what else is happening in the device (other background processes, battery/wireless/notification status bar updates, etc...), then yes, multiple messages can be processed within one screen refresh cycle, but do not count on it... there is no guarantee. 100,000  messages being invoke by a single thread on a single 1Ghz core is going to swamp the device and again, depending upon the OS, it will get thottled... back to the 16.6 refresh cycle... ;-)

Comment: Okay but even if I only have it update 10 times throughout the whole thing it still becomes unresponsive. But just putting a Thread.Sleep(1); after the call to update makes all the problems go away. The worker thread, though, is taking more than 1ms between the incremental updates so I would think the UI thread would still get that 1ms of free time. Do you know what's going on there?

Comment: @user875234 It is just the pure overhead of invoking an action/message on the main/thread, you have "captured" value instances that are being preserved via the stack as they are being used across threads. A spin-style tight loop like that is just not a practical thing to do (on any OS).

Comment: @Dweeberly try doing this while updating a `TextView` on `Xamarin.Android`, the JNI wrapper in Xamarin's SDK for setting the Java String value on a `TextView` has a **new** C# string being instanced on every call that is a copy of the original C# string, 100,000 calls like this and you just crashed the Mono GC/runtime as it can not keep up with the instancing of the new strings and GC'ing of the old strings. An Android ANR might happen, but usually a Mono out-of-native-memory crash will happen.